# "Addiction level" feature

Tags: feature-request

Could we have an addiction level feature which was displayed on user's profiles? This idea is completely nicked from GTA4, although SO might need slightly politer categories! How might such a rating be calculated?

Comment: We already have two of them: rep points and badges!

Comment: I think addiction is a problem - but none of the addicts will see it as such...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would like to leave the house at some point. So please dont.

Comment: It's far too cold to leave your house. Unless you live close to one of your volcanoes.

Comment: I use a mini volcano to keep warm at night.

Answer (score 5):

```
double RPM = /* get refreshes per minute somehow */; //Refreshes per Minute
int GM = 100 * User.GoldBadgeCount; // Gold coefficient
int SM = 50 * User.SilverBadgeCount; // Silver coefficient
int BM = 10 * User.BronzeBadgeCount; // Bronze coefficient

double stat = RPM * (GM + SM + BM) / User.Reputation;
// stat is a completely useless statistic
```

Comment: You're employed as a programmer, and *this* is how you write out formulas? WTF is wrong with you? I have to infer that you are an awful programmer, not even worth the salt he licks.

Comment: Who says he is employed as programmer?

Comment: He        does.

Comment: He is full of lies and ponies.

Comment: You trust                            him?

Comment: Not    anymore.

Comment: Fixed that for you.

Comment: Can someone upvote Welbog for the edit..... I really wish we could upvote after an edit. And the editor gets the rep.

Comment: Diago, just give me the ability to ban TheTXI and we'll call it even.

Comment: Better yet, just ban TheTXI directly! Remove the middle man in the arrangement to promote efficiencies.

Comment: Yeah! Mod Wars! But wait! We need someone ahead of Jeff on Meta...

Comment: +1 to Welbog for trying to make the banning of TheTXI more efficient for everyone.

Comment: @TheTXI: Every second you exist is agony to me.

Comment: @Welbog: Well then: Diago, do not ban TheTXI!

Comment: Don't worry everyone, Welbog is a masochist.

Comment: @TheTXI: That's probably the best explanation I can think of for why I would choose to interact with you on a regular basis in IRC. Either I'm a masochist or I'm morbidly curious about how someone as dumb as you can moderate a website without it crashing down horribly around your hooves. I suppose that just means that Jeff has restricted the abilities that moderators have on their sites. If anything can go wrong, TXI will make it go wrong; it's just a matter of time. Since this is true, and it hasn't happened yet, I need only wait. I'll be there, TXI, laughing at you when you ruin everything.

Comment: @Welbog: I'm sorry, I'm too busy playing baseball in the data center to read your entire comment.

Comment: Only one small problem with that, when a moderator is banned he can.... Unban himself. We tested this. Already. Destroy account is about the only other option, although I assume Jeff hit a flag on the moderators accounts that says can't be deleted. I **AM NOT WILLING TO BE THE SCAPEGOAT**. K, Thx, Bye.

Comment: Then let me do it.

Answer (score 2):

Having only played GTA4 long enough to wonder why I bothered, I'm not sure how the addiction levels work.  But I'm skeptical that they'd provide a lot more information than the woot and fanatic badges.  Besides, I don't want on display just how much time I waste on this site; that's embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage of posts on the site? Average posts per day? (The second would favor people that are very active even if not in the community for very long.) Number of consecutive days of visits up to now and longest run ever? (This would also tell me when I finally get my fanatic badge.)

Answer (score 0):

I thought that was what the Reputation Points where there for? With a 200 a day cap your addicted if you start hitting 5000+ rep?

I honestly find it rare for old answers to quickly provide me a rep boost once the question has left the front page.

<sub>Yes, there is a hint of sarcasm and boredom in there somewhere</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself with three (3) Fanatic badges, while still posting good quality answers (because just turning up isn't really playing), then you're probably a little addicted.

It's a polite way now to have it show up only as a nice little badge on your profile and not this "Crack rock level" tick-ticker of addiction.